# 正規表現で句読点にマッチしたいが、括弧内の句読点にはマッチさせたくない

Tags: ruby, 正規表現

文字列を"、"で分割したいです
句読点にマッチしたいが、括弧内の句読点にはマッチさせたくない

例:
aa（bb、cc）、dd、ff
↓(''の部分をマッチしたい)
aa（bb、cc）'、'dd'、'ff

環境はruby 2.3です

Comment: カッコがネストすることはありえますか？

Comment: 括弧がネストすることはないです

Answer (score 1):

もっと他にいい方法があるかもしれませんが、こういうのを思いつきました。

```
"aa（bb、cc）、dd、ff".scan(/[^、]*（.*）[^、]*|[^、]+/)
#=> ["aa（bb、cc）", "dd", "ff"]
```